# How to store a property in a session with express-session?

Tags: api, session, crud, express-session

I have the following code:

```js
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;
  // dummy local database with custome helper functions to look up a user:
  db.users.findByUsername(username, (err, user) => {
    if (!user) return res.status(403).json({ msg: "No user found!" });
    if (user.password === password) {

      // Adding properties to session
      req.session.authenticated = true;
      req.session.user = {
        username,
        password,
      };
      console.log(req.session);
      // Session is printed in terminal with the above properties. Works fine up to here.
      res.redirect("/shop");
    } else {
      res.status(403).json({ msg: "Bad Credentials" });
    }
  });
});
```

I used `express-session` to create a session and i'm storing it in memory. I created a middleware that would allow a user to access a `/shop` page *only* if they're authenticated and have the `req.session.authenticated` property set to true. For some reason, after they log in, and they're redirected to the `/shop` page, the properties created in the session are no longer there. Here's the rest of the code:

Authentication middleware:

```js
function ensureAuthentication(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session.authenticated) {
    // Properties that were added upon logging in are not attached.
    return next();
  } else {
    res.status(403).json({ msg: "You're not authorized to view this page" });
  }
}
```

Shop page

```js
app.get("/shop", ensureAuthentication, (req, res) => {
  // Send the user object to the view page:
  res.render("shop", { user: req.session.user });
});
```

Any opinions? Am I missing something here? Does the order of how I have the endpoints written matter?